# EF Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'HubxEnrollment' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: asp.net-core

[image: table]

I have set it to yes. I don't know why the issue is popping up.

This is my entity class:

```
public class HubxEnrollment : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("HubxEnrollmentID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
}
```

And this service code:

```
HubxEnrollment hubxEnrollment = null; 

if (hubxEnrollmentModel.HubxEnrollmentID == 0) //(hubxEnrollment != null)
{
    hubxEnrollment = new HubxEnrollment();
    hubxEnrollmentModel.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(hubxEnrollmentModel, hubxEnrollment);

    hubxEnrollment.IsDeleted = false;

    _hubxEnrollmentRepository.Create(hubxEnrollment);
    _hubxEnrollmentRepository.SaveChanges();

    return new JsonModel()
               {
                   data = hubxEnrollment,
                   Message = StatusMessage.HubxDataCreated,
                   StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCodes.OK
               };
}
```

Any idea what is causing this issue? Issue is generated during saving.

Comment: Any chance the Automapper mappings are explicitly setting the value of `Id` in the `hubxEnrollment` class? Since it's an `IDENTITY` column, you should *not* set any value at all for `Id` in your C# code - let the database handle this for you

Comment: No it is not setting any Id

Comment: You're checking `if (hubxEnrollmentModel.HubxEnrollmentID == 0)` - so the model class **has** a value (0) for the `HubxEnrollmentID` set - are you explicitly **excluding** that `Id` in your AutoMapper mapping config? If not - try to do that!

Comment: i think you have to use `ValueGeneratedNever()` on the endity you are interested in having a custom identity